# Preallocating memory for objects on the stack rather then on the heap JAVA

Tags: java, memory, new-operator

consider the LinkedList exemple in c, where i explicitly preallocated N nodes structs on the stack to use as a pool or a stack of nodes, instead of using the slow mallocs and frees, (i dont need the functionality of freeing a node in run so a stack would do):

```
#define N 40000

typedef struct node_t {
    void * ele;
    struct node_t * next;
}node,*Pnode;

node Stack[N];//memory allocation for the linkedlist nodes
int sp=0;

Pnode createNode(void * x) {
    Pnode temp=&Stack[sp++];
    temp->ele=x;
    temp->next=NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

when i tried to immitate the idea above in JAVA, thats what i came up with... can you complete the class to make Node[] stack  be an array of nodes object which memory is preallocated in STACK?

```
public class Node<E>  {

    private final static int n = 40000;
    private static Node[] stack = ?
    private static int sp = 0;

    private E ele;
    private Node next;

    private Node () {}
    public Node createNode(E e) {
        stack[sp].ele=e;
        stack[sp].next=null;
        return stack[sp++];
    }
}
```

Basiclly i want to know this because I know what i want from my program to be able to do, and I know that i dont need the ability to free and reuse a block of memory, I want to be able to allocate a Node object fast as lightining even when my program is almost having a HEAP OVERFLOW. the Stack of nodes with a max capacity of N and a running index like i did would be perfect for me...

Answer (score 6):

No. Java doesn't have an explicit mechanism to allocate memory on the stack.

Using `new` is the only way to allocate memory. It is then up to the JVM to decide where that memory comes from, and to manage it from that point on.

**edit:** I've just had a closer look at your code. You're not even allocating memory on the stack. What you appear to be doing is having a stack data structure that lives on the data segment, and that you manage yourself.

In Java, there's no direct equivalent of:

```
node Stack[N];
```

In other words, there's no way to construct `N` objects in a contiguous block of memory. You have to allocate an array of `N` references, and then create `N` objects.

That said, bear in mind that in modern JVMs, `new` essentially amounts to a pointer bump. This is: (a) cheap; (b) similar to what you're doing with `sp`.

Comment: "Using new is the only way to dynamically allocate memory", but i am NOT trying to allocate it dynamically, is it possible then?

Comment: @OfekRon: As I said, there's no mechanism to force the JVM to allocate memory on the stack.

Comment: @your edit, whats the diffrence? as far as i know all variables (correct me if im wrong) that you declare of in a program is getting its memory allocated on the stack. (by the compiler)

Comment: @your second edit, but what if N is very big integer? if it will fit the heap it would make all my "new" calls much slower

Comment: @OfekRon: The stack, the heap and the data segment are three distinct entities and should not be confused.

Comment: @OfekRon: IMO you're optimizing prematurely. Code it up, profile the result and **if it's too slow**, present your specific code with your exact benchmarks. Then we'll be able to give you specific advice on how to make it faster.

Comment: no im not, it actually came up after ive done it both ways in C, once i allocated about 50million nodes with malloc, then by the way i described at the question, it was way ahead by minutes... i wanted to check if its the same with java...

Comment: @OfekRon: As I've been trying to explain, C results don't automatically apply to Java. On my PC, allocating 50 million objects like yours and storing them in a Java array takes ~10 seconds. Anyway, this discussion isn't really going anywhere until we see some actual code & benchmarks.

Comment: In any event, there is _no way_ in Java to control where your objects get allocated.  There is only `new`, and the JVM decides where the objects get allocated in the end.  There isn't anything you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

> can you complete the class to make Node[] be array of nodes object in the STACK?

No.  Java manages the allocation of memory for you, based on its own heuristics.  To my knowledge there's nothing in the JLS that guarantees where a particular object will be allocated.

My question to you is - why do you *want* this to be allocated on the stack?  Do you think you know better than Hotspot where the most performant location for this data is, based on the internal state of the garbage collector?  (Based on my admittedly non-expert knowledge, these objects would be best placed in an Eden pool on the heap anyway.)

One of the things you'll need to learn with Java is to *just let go*, and trust the VM's decisions about where to allocate memory.  So long as you avoid writing convoluted algorithms, it generally does a very good job indeed of these decisions (typically better than a developer can, because it considers information available at runtime rather than being forced down a static dichotomy when writing code.)

Comment: It is because I know what i want from my program to be able to do, and I know that i dont need the ability to free and reuse a block of memory, I want to be able to allocate a Node  object  fast as lightining even when my program is almost having HEAP OVERFLOW.

Comment: thats exactly what i had a problem with... my program went slow as i allocated more and more Nodes, the same occured with the C code above when i used malloc instead of just preallocating the nodes

Comment: Have you used a profiler or `-verbose:gc` to determine that the slowness is down to the memory location that the new objects are assigned to?  Generally speaking, even if the heap is nearly full, allocating the required chunk of memory should be a constant-time operation (in the absence of fragmentation, which should be the case here).

Answer (score 1):

What you appear to want is an object pool.

A simple pool is to use an ArrayList

```
public class Node<E>  {

    private final static int MAX_SIZE = 40000;
    private final static List<Node> freeNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    private E ele;
    private Node next;

    private Node () {}

    public static Node<E> acquireNode(E e) {
        Node node = freeNodes.size() > 0 
                    ? freeNodes.remove(freeNodes.size()-1) 
                    : new Node();
        node.ele = e;
        return node;
    }

    public static void freeNode(Node<E> node) {
        if(freeNodes.size() < MAX_SIZE) {
            node.next = null;
            freeNodes.add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using a LinkedList which is bound to create lots of objects, I suggest using a different structure such as an ArrayList or RingBuffer as neither of these need these nodes in the first place. (The fastest way to do something is to not do it at all ;)

Comment: I try to avoid linkedlists as much as possible, espicially in java, but for exemple id rather merge a 2Billion nodes sorted linked list with a 4Billion nodes sorted linked list, then the same with arrays.

Comment: what you did there DOESNT count, and doesnt do what i wanted, cause WITHIN the array list, there is nothing, I have to fill the arraylist with new Nodes that alloacated by new - on the heap, which is not what i wanted.

Comment: If you have a 6 Billion node linked list you will have about 144 GB in object overhead alone (approx 32 bytes for the Node + 16 bytes header of the object)  I would suggest using a off heap memory if you have billions of objects/records (to merge or otherwise)

Comment: You can't create multiple objects at once in Java. An array is an array of references (or primitives), not objects. This is the closest you can get.